# Is it possible to set the focus value on a qx1 via sdk

Tags: sdk, camera, sony

I use the QX1 in manual focus mode, but I want to save the current focus value using the sdk and restore it AFTER the camera has been powered off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately getting and setting the actual focus values is not supported.  You can set the focus mode but not the values themselves.

Comment: Do you think hat this might be supported in future on any sony camera with sdk/api support?